# Error converting AXValue to CFTypeRef in AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue on MacOS

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, swiftui, appkit

I am trying to get the text range globally on MacOS from Accessibility API, `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue` function. But having an error converting AXValue to CFTypeRef.

This snippet I am [referring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6642380/11036816) to

Variables:

```
var focusedElement: CFTypeRef?
                
var rangeValue: AXValue? = nil
```

First Attempt:

```
if AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(
   focusedElement as! AXUIElement,
   kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute as CFString,
   (CFTypeRef *)&rangeValue) == AXError.success {

   } /* Compile error: Cannot convert value of type 'AXValue' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<AnyObject>>') */
```

Second Attempt:

```
if AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(
    focusedElement as! AXUIElement,
    kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute as CFString, 
    ((rangeValue as CFTypeRef) as? UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>)!)
    == AXError.success {

}         /* Throw Error: Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x7fdf2d8a75a8) to 'Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>>' */
```

How to achieve this in Swift?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575195/how-to-use-axuielementcopyattributevalue-from-swift ? `(CFTypeRef *)&rangeValue` that's Objective-C casting.